# Testing HTTP with mockbackends doesn't work

Tags: angular, http

Try to make a test, but get this error message:

> Expected object to be a kind of Object, but was Response with status:
>   null null for URL: null.

Any idea what's missing here?

login.component.ts:

```
loginEvent(username, passw) {
      let obj = {
          user: username,
          pass: passw
      };

  if (this.validation(obj)) { 
      this.httpService.loginPostToServer(obj).subscribe(
          (response) => this.saveTokenToLocalstorage(response),
          (error) => console.log(error)
      );
    }
  };
```

http.service.ts:

```
loginPostToServer(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'login', data);
}
```

Test:

```
import { async, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpModule, Http, ResponseOptions, Response, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';

describe('HttpService', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [ HttpService, MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions,
    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    }],
    imports: [ HttpModule ]
    });
});

it('should be created', inject([HttpService], (service: HttpService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
}));

it('should construct', async(inject(
    [HttpService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
})));

describe('loginPostToServer', () => {
    const mockResponse = {
    success: true,
    token: "sample token",
    user: "john"
    };

    const fakeUser = {
    user: "john",
    pass: "1234"
    };

    it('should parse response', async(inject(
    [HttpService, MockBackend], (service, mockBackend) => {

    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(conn => {
        conn.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse) })));
    });

    const result = service.loginPostToServer(fakeUser);

    result.subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).toEqual({
        success: true,
        token: "sample token",
        user: "john"
        });
    });
    })));
});
});
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the response object returned from the http call *contains* the data you want, but is not itself what you want.

To access the data inside of the request (i.e. the body of the request), you need to call the .json() method:

```
  if (this.validation(obj)) { 
      this.httpService.loginPostToServer(obj).subscribe(
          (response) => this.saveTokenToLocalstorage(response.json()), // .json() added here
          (error) => console.log(error)
      );
    }
  };
```